# Daily Recurrence Invoices Check

Tags: php, mysql, invoice, invoices

My situation as follow:

I'm building up an invoice system, I have almost everything done, except the invoices recurrence. Here is what I'm trying to do without success.

**The condition:**

My condition to generate a new recurrence incoice is ->

1. contract must be active.
2. reference must be equal to PA.
3. generate invoices only to contract that do not have invoices yet. (How can check it)

I will run the script with cron, and it will run everyday, then I'm going to generate invoices daily if the contract do not have one. 
If contracts have invoice for this date then do nothing - exit.

Here I have a piece of code in SQL, that I'm retrieving everybody that has invoices to this date (NOW for month and year).

**Some usefull information:**

I have **324 active contracts** with invoices already generated in the follow query.

```
SELECT contratos.id, contratos.idcliente, contratos.ativo, invoices.id as inv, invoices.due_date, invoices.contratoid 
FROM contratos 
LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.contratoid = contratos.id 
WHERE contratos.ativo = 1 
AND invoices.referencia = 'PA' 
AND YEAR(due_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(due_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY invoices.id
```

I have **368 actives contracts** in this other query.

```
SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE active=1
```

Then I know **I have 44 contracts without invoices** and I know I need to generate new invocies for the 44 contracts.

My question is how can I retrieve this 44 contracts and show it in my first query, It can be a null (no problem), the important to me id the Contract ID.

If I'm not clear enough please let me know.

**Thanks Community.**

**[EDITED]
Summary**

- I run my first query and got results of 324 lines.
- Then run the second query and compare the result of query1 and query2
- the lines that does'nt match is the difference and I need to generate
  invoices to them.

*I really would like to do this in my query (one query) and not in my code.*

Comment: The LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.contratoid = contratos.id do not return the null of 44 contract without contracts, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LEFT JOIN is returning the invoices records being filled with all NULL values.  When you are requiring invoices.referencia to = 'PA', that will eliminate all the records that are completely null (negating your outer join).

Comment: But I really need to filter by PA without this drafts come along. PA equal to Parcel, quota, etc.. I had try reoving the line PA and it return to me 377, 'bause it include the drafts along.

Comment: This is *truly* a hack, but you could us IFNULL to provide a default value for invoices.referencia in your where clause.  So the clause would look like 'AND IFNULL(invoices.referencia, 'PA') = 'PA'.

Comment: does not work here, it returns the same result as before. I would like to compare the actives contracts with the result of query 1. But I would like to do it in a unique query and not in my code.

Comment: Is the column due_date in the invoices table?  If so you'll have to do the same trick with the IFNULL for those as well.

Comment: Oh! I see, yeah the column due_date is in the invoice table. I will repeat the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I had try and nothing, use the same trick to both collumns .  the result is the same as before. Anyway thanks for your time! The Best Regards!